# Laravel 5.0 Undefined variable result

Tags: php, laravel, variables, undefined

I have a form that a user enters and takes the entry and queries the database and returns to a view. I have managed to get one query working but when trying to work on another query it returns an undefined variable error in the view. See below:

Routes

```
Route::get('/shopsales', 'shopsalescontroller@index');
```

Controller

```
class shopsalescontroller extends Controller
```

{

```
 public function index()
{
    $storeNum = request('storeNum');


   $result = shopsales::where('StoreNumber','=',$storeNum)
        ->get();

    return view('shopsales',compact('result'));


}
```

}

shopsales view

```
<section>
  <center><h1><STRONG>Query Data</STRONG></h1></center>
    <ul>
      @foreach ($result as $results)
        <li>Report Name = {{ $results->ReportName}} | Report ID = {{ $results->ReportID}} | Store Number = {{ $results->StoreNumber}} | Store Name = {{ $results->StoreName}} | Week Number = {{ $results->WeekNumber}} |
            Year = {{ $results->Year}} | PerfumeName = {{ $results->PerfumeName}} | Units Sold = {{ $results->UnitsSold}} | Sales = {{ $results->Sales}}
        </li>
        <br>
      @endforeach
    </ul>

</section>
```

I have used the exact code for the query that is working, struggling to understand why this is not.

Comment: before return to the view can u check is there correct result set in your controller, using dd($result);

Comment: I cant even access the view without the same error displaying even though i have commented out all the code.

Answer (score 0):

try this

in `App\Route`

```
Route::resource('/shopsales','ShopSalecontroller');
```

This routes the following actions: `index`, `create`, `store`, `show`, `edit`, `update` and `destroy`.

add this function to shopsales model

```
public function scopeNumber($query, $number){
    if($number != null){
        $query->where('storeNumber','=', "$number");
    }
}
```

in `ShopSalesController` index:

```
public function index(Request $request){
   $result = shopsales::get()->number($request->storeNumber)->all();
   return view('shopsales',compact('result'));
}
```

Remember to have in the index view a form with the field storeNumber

Comment: Thanks for the help, just able to take a look at this now and getting the same error.

Comment: I cant even access the view without the same error displaying even though i have commented out all the code.

Comment: Solved, though sorry for wasting your time, some of my views should of had a capital letter in them, fixed that cleared the view cache and now i have the queries.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function index()
{
   $storeNum = request('storeNum');
   $result = shopsales::where('StoreNumber','=',$storeNum)
        ->get();
    return view('shopsales',['result'=>compact('result')]);
}
```

Change your controller code like above.
Also check if $result is not null.

Comment: I cant even access the view without the same error displaying even though i have commented out all the code.

Comment: Solved, though sorry for wasting your time, some of my views should of had a capital letter in them, fixed that cleared the view cache and now i have the queries.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
public function storeCheckout(Request $request) {
$storeNum=$request->get('storeNum');
$result = shopsales::where('StoreNumber','=',$storeNum)
        ->get();

    return view('shopsales',compact('result'));

}
```

Comment: Just literally got it working, was really silly, some of my views included a capital letter which i did not have on my form. Thanks for replying.

Answer (score 0):

Solved, though sorry for wasting your time, some of my views should of had a capital letter in them, fixed that cleared the view cache and now i have the queries.

Answer (score -1):

in action index
change var $result to $results

in view index
    @foreach ($results as $result)
    @endforeach